# Nginx OCSP Stapling is Not Working

Tags: nginx, ubuntu, ssl-certificate, openssl, ocsp

I have generated the certificates as given below:

```
Root-CA  ->  Intermediate-CA  ->  Server

Root-CA:
rootca.key
rootca.crt

Intermediate-CA:
intermediateca.key
intermediateca.crt

Server:
server.key
server.crt
```

My openssl.conf for Server:

```
[ server_cert ]
authorityInfoAccess = OCSP;URI:http://www.example.com

[ ocsp ]
basicConstraints = CA:FALSE
subjectKeyIdentifier = hash
authorityKeyIdentifier = keyid,issuer
keyUsage = critical, digitalSignature
extendedKeyUsage = critical, OCSPSigning
```

My Nginx conf:

```
server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        listen [::]:443 SSL;
        server_name www.example.com;

        ssl_certificate  /home/user/conffiles/server+intermediateca.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /home/user/conffiles/server.key;

        ssl_ocsp on;
        ssl_stapling on;
        ssl_stapling_verify on;
        ssl_trusted_certificate /home/user/conffiles/rootca+intermediateca.crt;
}
```

I am getting an Nginx Error:

```
[error] 4318#4318: OCSP responder sent invalid "Content-Type" header: "text/html; charset=utf-8" while requesting certificate status, responder: www.example.com, peer: 192.168.10.100:80, certificate: "/home/user/conffiles/server+intermediateca.crt"
```

Also, I am not getting any output with the following command:

```
echo QUIT | openssl s_client -connect www.example.com:443 -status 2> /dev/null | grep -A 17 'OCSP response:' | grep -B 17 'Next Update'
```

I don't understand what is wrong with the conf files. How can I configure OCSP in Nginx?

Please help me, I need this bug fixed. I appreciate your time. Thank you.

Comment: @anx How? Can you please explain?

Comment: Are you possibly confused about roles? Nginx is merely *requesting* OCSP, providing OCSP *responses* is the job of the certificate authority. Please clarify your question, who signed those certificates?

Comment: Those are self-signed certificates. Root-CA sign by Root-CA, Intermediate-CA sign by Root-CA, Server sign by Intermediate-CA. Check the generated certificates above.

Comment: So you have not setup an OCSP responder?

Comment: I want to setup an OCSP responder but I don't know how, please help me, how can I do it?

Comment: @anx can you please help me with this?